# Unicode in SQL Server unique constraints

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, unicode, collation

Consider the following script - the second INSERT statement throws a primary key violation.

```
BEGIN TRAN

CREATE TABLE UnicodeQuestion
(
    UnicodeCol NVARCHAR(100)
    COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
)

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UX_UnicodeCol
ON UnicodeQuestion ( UnicodeCol )

INSERT INTO UnicodeQuestion (UnicodeCol) VALUES (N'ae')
INSERT INTO UnicodeQuestion (UnicodeCol) VALUES (N'æ')

ROLLBACK
```

As I understand it, if I want to have my index treat these values separately, I need to use a binary collation. But there are many binary collations, and they have individual cultures in their names! I don't want culture-sensitive treatment...

Which collation should I use when storing arbitrary Unicode data in nvarchar columns?

Comment: If you were happy with `Latin1_General_CI_AI`, is `Latin1_General_BIN` not acceptable?

Comment: Probably, yes :) I'm just confused as to why there's a culture-aspect at all, when it's supposedly a binary collation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Unicode data [it is irrelevant what binary collation you choose](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143350%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

> For Unicode data types, data comparisons are based on the Unicode
>   code points. For binary collations on Unicode data types, the locale
>   is not considered in data sorts. For example, Latin_1_General_BIN and
>   Japanese_BIN yield identical sorting results when used on Unicode
>   data.

The reason for having locale specific `BIN` collations is that this determines the code page used when dealing with non Unicode data.